# .on not working when using variable

Tags: jquery

I am trying to attach a function to the keyup event but it does not work when I am using a variable:

```
var inputTextarea = $('#input');
inputTextarea.on('keyup', updateSizeTextarea);
```

It does work well when I use the selector directly:

```
$('#input').on('keyup', updateSizeTextarea);
```

P.S: After finding thousands of answer on this site, I am finally posting a question myself!

Comment: Are you setting `inputTextarea` **before** the element exists by any chance? If the code is exactly as above it works.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, don't be afraid to ask, but if you can manage to replicate that issue in a fiddle, you get a gold star

Comment: It's generally good practice when posting code about HTML interactions that you also post the relevant HTML code so that people can attempt to recreate the error (and thus begin fixing it).

Comment: @Jhecht - lets assume the HTML is `<input id="input" />`

Comment: Agreed with @FelixKling - the code, as posted, is identical. If it doesn't work, then it's because you're not showing something relevant.

Comment: jsfiddle example: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/nr0ap460/1/)

Comment: @adeneo we obviously can't assume that, since it works just fine with simply that HTML. There's obviously something we're not being informed about

Comment: @Fabien your fiddle does not work because you forgot a closing curly brace after the `alert()` call

Comment: Have you the code nested in `$(document).ready(function(){your-code-here})`; Otherwise its probable that the code is run before the DOM element is built by the browser, so it doesn't find the #input textarea and can't attach the listener.

Comment: Jhecht: updated, does not get it why it works there...[link](http://jsfiddle.net/nr0ap460/2/)

Comment: Could it be that you have to elements with the same id? If so, only the first gets the event when assigning it to a variable. I've tried it on the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is the code closest to what I have on my page:
http://jsfiddle.net/nr0ap460/8/

```
var inputTextarea = $('#input');
$(document).ready(function() {
    inputTextarea.on('keyup', function() {alert("does not work")});
});
```

So it seems that it is a DOM loading issue, I assign my variable outside the ready. If I move it inside the ready function it then works (script is in header)

Comment: Congratulations, you've just learned what it means to make sure the DOM is ready before you try to fetch elements from it

Comment: Thanks guys for pointing me to the right direction!

Comment: I recommend to read the jQuery tutorial which explains exactly that: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/#launching-code-on-document-ready, http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/